# wpf controls traveling around the grid/stack panel and not staying put

Tags: wpf, grid, controls, stackpanel

I am building a user control in WPF and put a few buttons in a stackpanel laying inside a grid. Problem is that when I build the app and run it, the buttons "sail around" and don't stay where I put them in the designer window. Is there any attribute I'm missing(or some sort of container?)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the alignment properties of your grid:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
...
</Grid>
```